# I want to display email domain and rest part in two different columns using Substring or Partition By

Tags: sql, substring

I have column of e-mail addresses with a domain as (`@Gmail.com`, `@Hotmail.com`, `@live.com` etc).

I need to separate `@Gmail.com`, `@Hotmail.com`, `@live.com` address from others and write them in one column and rest part before `@` in another column.

E.g : abc@gmail.com

Expected output :

```
c1 column = abc 
c2 column = gmail.com
```

How can I achieve this using substring or partition by?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a substr and row_number()

```
      Select 
 Substr(email,INSTR(email,'@')+1, length(email)) as "Domain", 
   Substr(email,1,INSTR(email,'@')-1) as 
  "User", row_number() over 
   (partition by 
    Substr(email,INSTR(email,'@')+1,length(email)) order
   by Substr(email,INSTR(email,'@')+1, length(email)) )
from table;
```

[image]